# Apply Background color for Promoted List in SharePoint 2013 using Content or Script Edtor

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part

I have been tasked to apply background color for promoted links using Script and Content editor web part, can any one help me? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean the metro style icons then you can override the default CSS to make them a different colour.

```
<style type='text/css'>
div.ms-tileview-tile-content {
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Add a CEWP to a page and edit the source.  Paste in the above and set the colour as you want it.  I would also suggest you hide the CEWP.